# How to retry a loop in perl

Tags: perl, foreach, exception, try-catch, eval

I am doing a Eval to check whether if server goes down

```
    eval{
      foreach(){
        Processing 10,000 UPCS in API one by one
        }
      };
    if($@){
      continue; 
      sleep(1200);
    }
```

The above code works fine but the problem is if server goes down it is skipping the current UPC(Loop) and it id processing the next UPC(Loop).

Instead of skipping the UPC(Loop) i have to retry the same upc if server goes down?

Answer (score 3):

Move the eval into the loop and use redo:

```
foreach ... {
    eval {
    };
    if ($@) {
        sleep 1200;
        redo;
    }
}
```

though I'm not sure what your `continue` was supposed to be doing; I doubt it did what you expected.